# Getting 401 unauthorized for Laravel sanctum

Tags: vue.js, axios, laravel-7, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel Sanctum with Vuejs SPA. Both reside on same top level domain

```
Laravel backend : app.demo.localhost
Vue SPA : app-spa.demo.localhost
```

Login and logout (endpoints) are working correctly when called from VueJS SPA using axios and XSRF-TOKEN is succesfully set, but when I call other api end points it gives me 401 unauthorized.

In axios this is being set

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

I have the below configurations

In Laravel .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.demo.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=app-spa.demo.localhost
```

In Routes/Api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('api/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});
```

In cors.php

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'logout'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: You don't have it shown above, have you enabled the sanctum middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`?
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authentication

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem on my production server, using react and axios. O development server it works fine

Comment: anyone solve this? I am getting a success login with a custom guard. But subsequent requests fail even through xsrf token is set etc...

Comment: Facing the same problem. Please provide answer if someone as found it.

Comment: I'm struggling with a very similar issue...POST requests seem to work (login, logout), however the GET /api/user is returning 401. I'm on Laravel 10, using Postman client. I have an older Laravel 8 app that I booted up and tried the same Postman requests and the GET /api/user returns 200...pretty stumped atm. Did an eyeball diff of the 2 server-side config files (8 vs 10) but no major differences as far as I can tell. Referer header is set. Also not sure if this matters but I'm running Laravel via sail (may affect port number?)

Answer (score 39):

If you are using php artisan serve add the port number to SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS. So if your port number is 8000:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.demo.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=app-spa.demo.localhost:8000
```

Your SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS must match the url in your browser. The port number should not be on the SESSION_DOMAIN.

Comment: I added port number to the SESSION_DOMAIN setting and that made it return 401 - i removed the port number and it worked right away - thanks!

Comment: by default `APP_URL` is stateful. fixing `APP_URL` in my `.env` solved my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Following are the 8 steps that I follow while setting up Laravel sanctum check if you missed anything

**Step1** `composer require laravel/sanctum`

**Step2**  `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider`

**Step3** `php artisan migrate` (you can ignore this if you're using spa)

**Step4**  uncomment this line from app/http/kernel.php `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,`

**Step5** In config/cors.php update `'supports_credentials' => true,`

**Step6** In .env file update `SESSION_DRIVER=cookie` & add new line of `SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost` (even if your using any port like 8080 just mention **localhost** in session_domain)

**Step7**  In config/sanctum.php add your client domain along with port(if local) in stateful as follows, in my case for vue CLI it's usually `localhost:8080` & for nuxt its `localhost:3000` , code is as follows

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:8000,localhost:8080,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

Mostly if your stateful (step7) is not setup properly you will get 401 unauthorized or it will try to redirect you to the home page along with cors policy error

**Step8** Do not forget to `await` until `sanctum/csrf-cookie` promise is resolved

```
    async login() {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie");

      await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/login", {
        email: "kunal@gmail.com",
        password: "password",
      });

      let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user");
      console.log(response.data);
    },
```

Comment: Thanks @Kanul Rajput for this comprehensive answer. My login happens in a guard _before_ I can make this call, which I think may be causing me problems. Do you know if there is there any way I can 'manually' trigger whatever process happens when the login is called with the XSRF token?

Comment: Thank you so much , it's was EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful in my case

Comment: Step 7 was the blocker for me. I set `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:3000`, I just had to remove the `http://`

All you just need is `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000`

Comment: (for multiple guards) Step 8 could be adding additional guards to 'guard' => ['web', 'admin'] in config/sanctum.php

Answer (score 9):

For anyone dealing with localhost:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie    
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost    
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080(port number you use)
```

Answer (score 4):

For me i just had to place the host with port number:

> SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:5173

and it started working.
Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem. I configured all the options according to the official documentation, but I couldn't get the authorization.

Then I use routes/web.php instead of routes/api.php, so I can use sanctum middleware very well.

Now the problem seems obvious，Axios withCredentials maybe need to place in the correct way.

```
const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    withCredentials: true
})
```

maybe not work. So I add `{withCredentials: true}` like

```
http.get('/api/whoami', {withCredentials: true})
  .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
```

Then it works.

But the very strange thing is that it is normal now, no matter whether I clear the browser cache, cookies or Laravel's various caches, there is no previous situation

Comment: man... That was the only solution worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I setup the domain in the wrong place.
I thought was an array of domains, in `config/sanctum.php`, but not, needs to be placed within the string:

OK:

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,myownlocaldomain.test,myownlocaldomain.test:8080', <-------- OK
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

BAD:

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        'myownlocaldomain.test', <----- BAD
        'myownlocaldomain.test:8080', <---- BAD
    ))),
```

I hope I save days of work to someone else...

Answer (score 0):

My problema was.... (no read with attention)

If your SPA needs to authenticate with private / presence broadcast channels, **you should place the** Broadcast::routes method call within **your routes/api.php fil**e:

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found a solution.

My SPA is Vue v3 working on 3000 port.
Also my backend is working on 80 port. (laravel 8.1)

Make Stateful Domains in config/sanctum.php like that

```
 'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost:3000',
    env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
))),
```

Adding only one and correct domain on their, worked for me magically. I wrote before there whole possible variant of ports, it made me crazy and cost a couple days and nights.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10 with VueJs 3 and Sanctum package. I have solved this problem by setting `APP_URL=[my domain name]` in the `.env` file which the value matches the domain name in the web browser.

Give this a try. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You SPA which is intended to be a first party app is not a first party app if it's on different port. So it's just acting like a mobile app in your development environment.

For example

Laravel api

```
localhost:8000
```

Vuejs app

```
locahost:5781
```

So you need to authenticate it be sending an authorization header when developing in your localhost host.
**Note: Do this only in your local development enviroment. So put the code below in an if.**

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    // Do something before request is sent
    
    if(process.env.dev) {
       // accessToken was set after a successful login
       const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
    
       if (accessToken) config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
    

    return config
  },
error => Promise.reject(error),
)
```