# Error 401: Unauthorized on Laravel Sanctum Authentication and Vue

Tags: laravel, cookies, vuejs3, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

I get a status error code when I try to access the data after logging in.
I am getting the XRSF token when someone attempts to log in but can't the user data back.

Below is my useAuth.js code

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function useAuth() {

    const login = async (credentials) => {
        await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie') // ! STATUS CODE - 204 - Ok
    
        await axios.post('/login', credentials) // ! STATUS CODE - 200 - Ok

        let response = await axios.get('/api/user')
        console.log(response)                   // ! STATUS CODE - 401 - UNATHORIZED
    }


    return {
        login
    }

}
```

My routes/api.php code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

My .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1
```

I tried to change SESSION_DRIVER to cookie but brings the same result as file

Main App.vue code

```
<template>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="login(form)">
    <div>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" v-model="form.email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" v-model="form.password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
  
  import { reactive } from 'vue'
  import useAuth from './auth/useAuth'

  const { login } = useAuth()

  const form = reactive({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })

</script>
```

Anyone with an idea on how I can solve the problem

Thank you

Comment: is the user really loged in after?         await axios.post('/login', credentials) // ! STATUS CODE - 200 - Ok Can you try to dd ?

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in. Showing the user is now the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to send your token in Authorization header in this request

```
let response = await axios.get('/api/user')
```

So you must add your bearer token to authorization header like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer your_token`;
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but i tried that. Can you please also show how you can set the Xsrf token on the headers because that is where the problems come from. You example is on how i can set the JWT_token

Answer (score 0):

You also need to tell axios to include cookies when sending requests:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Also make sure cors.php has support_credentials set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might help, I did get an answer to this question after much research. Silly me

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1
```

The above code should be set to the exact domain port.

You can check for further assistance on the link below

[Getting 401 unauthorized for Laravel sanctum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421547/getting-401-unauthorized-for-laravel-sanctum)

MR_AMDEV answer.

Your all welcome